# Add target to UITextView and UILabel in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITable` and I have multiple labels and textviews in it. I want a method to be called when touchupinside event is triggered . I used `targetForAction` but i cannot specify `touchUpInside` event in it.And the textview is not editable

On a whole , i want  what a button does with `addTarget` to be done by textview and label. Please help me

Comment: for clickable label https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel is the best source to working with it other then UItextView have delegate being called when you start editing it so based on logic you can call any method at the delegate fire

Comment: Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it? Is `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` not sufficiant?

Comment: @Larme  in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` , how can I know if the touched object in `UITextView`

Comment: You can't really. But, if you just have one selectable item by cell, then it's up to your dataSource to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

add `Gesture` and try

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.doubleTapped(_:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
     yourlabel.tag = indexPath.row
    yourlabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    yourlabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

call method like

```
func doubleTapped(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        print(recognizer.view!.tag)

}
```

for textview

add `yourTextView.delegate = self`

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    //do continue your work
}
```

You can view other such methods [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate?language=swift).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much!  @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: You might also need `yourlabel.userInteractionEnabled = true` as @lou-franco suggested in another answer.

Comment: In my app it doesnt work , i tried the implementation above but still it doesnt register any gesture. please check on my question thanks. [https://stackoverflow.com/q/49092902/3974048](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49092902/3974048)

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure `userInteractionEnabled` is set to true.

Then, either

1. Use a [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi1m7TF5ffMAhVJs48KHRjcBNMQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FUIKit%2FReference%2FUITapGestureRecognizer_Class%2F&usg=AFQjCNEFAsfVhkVR80mmwf7Nb2dOUMMSwg&sig2=GDWCj64VxcrTJ05Xu5U5Zg)

   -or-
2. Subclass the views and implement `touchesBegan:withEvent:` to implement the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

In you `UITableViewController` you can add the following function.
Notice that table view cell is not exactly a button and that is the reason you cannot just `addTarget`. In this method you will select the current table cell and act accordingly.

```
class TableView: UITableViewController {

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 1: // Change password
      print("Change password")
    ....// Add your cases 
    default:
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Note: You can also add a `UIButton` inside the cell, but I don't think it is a great practice.