# How to add touch event / or gesture in my overlapping custom textviews - swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have been unable to make it work the gesture recognizer in my app.

Under `viewDidLoad` I added these

```
let orangeIndicatorTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.orangeIndicatorClick(_:)))
    orangeIndicatorTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    orangeIndicatorTap.delegate = self

    conceptMiddleOrangeIndicator.tag = 1
    conceptMiddleOrangeIndicator.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    conceptMiddleOrangeIndicator.addGestureRecognizer(orangeIndicatorTap)

    let greenIndicatorTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.greenIndicatorClick(_:)))
    greenIndicatorTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

    conceptMiddleGreenIndicator.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    conceptMiddleGreenIndicator.addGestureRecognizer(greenIndicatorTap)


    let purpleIndicatorTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.purpleIndicatorClick(_:)))
    greenIndicatorTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

    conceptMiddlePurpleColorIndicator.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    conceptMiddlePurpleColorIndicator.addGestureRecognizer(purpleIndicatorTap)
```

[image]

Is there any other way i could add a click event to my overlapping custom uitextviews?

Comment: What does “unable to make it work” mean? What actually happens when you run it?

Comment: why not listen to `UITextViewTextDidBeginEditing` event on your textviews instead of adding additional touch event on it?

Comment: I don't understand how these are even text views.

Comment: @robmayoff these are textviews I just remove the text as to make sure the question is about overlapping views

Comment: @robmayoff I use textviews instead of label because i can manipulate the text padding for alignment top or center etc in textviews.

Comment: Ok but you still haven’t explained how it actually behaves at runtime. Also, what are the frames of the text views, and how are you setting up the colored circles? You can edit your question to include these details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, It was because of an overlay that wasnt being removed correctly.

It seems that, it visibly is removed but logically underlying overlay views were not removed. That's why the gesture doesnt work.

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `touchesBegan` to identify which `view` has been touched.

use this code hope this help.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    if touch.view == yourView_outlet {
    // add your code here
    } else if touch.view == yourView_outlet {
    // add your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Do i need to register my iboutlet or something? because it didnt identified the if else statement

Comment: @David yes buddy and also make sure `UserInteraction` is enable

Comment: I tried to do as you said, It does detect touch but it didnt identify my uitextview. Can you please clarify thanks